# How to use two dimensional arrays, Inverses, and multiplication to get solutions to a given linear equation?

Tags: c, arrays, math, division

Given these equations:

ax + by = c

dx + ey = f

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main (void){
//Data
float extra;
float x[2];
float y[2];
float solution[2];
float coef[2][2];

printf("Give Numbers:\n");
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f"
,&coef[0][0],  &coef[0][1], &solution[0],
&coef[1][0],  &coef[1][1], &solution[1]);


// Create Determinant
float det;
det = (coef[0][0] * coef[1][1] - coef[0][1] * coef[1][0]);


//Setting the Inverse
extra = coef[0][0];
coef[0][0] =   coef[1][1] / det;
coef[1][1] = extra / det;
coef[1][0] = -coef[1][0] / det;
coef[0][1] =  -coef[0][1] / det;





//Multiplication
y[0] = (coef[1][1]*solution[0]-solution[1]*coef[0][1]) / det;
x[1] = (coef[0][0]*solution[1]-solution[0]*coef[1][0]) / det;

//Print statements
printf("'Y' = %f\n" , y[0]);
printf("'X' = %f\n" , x[1]);
printf("Det= %f\n",det);

}
```

I am writing a program to solve two simultaneous linear equations with two unknowns.

I have six single-precision floating-point numbers a, b, c, d, e, f each separated by whitespace.
These numbers are meant to be interpreted as the pair of equations
ax+by=c
dx+ey=f
To solve this, first put the coefficient into a two-by-two matrix:
[ a b ]
[ d e ]
And put the constant values into an array:
[ c f ]
Then invert the coefficient matrix by finding its determinant:
det = ( a*e - b*d )
If the determinant is 0, terminate at this point with the error message "too complicated"

The inverse of the coefficient matrix is then
[  e/det -b/det ]
[ -d/det  a/det ]
This should be multiplied by the constant array to yeild
[ (e*c-f*b)/det  (a*f-c*d)/det ]

EXAMPLE:

ax+by=c
dx+ey=f

CORRECT INPUT/OUTPUT

give numbers

1 2 3 4 5 6

x=-1.000000

y=2.000000

MY INPUT/OUTPUT

Give Numbers:

1 2 3 4 5 6

y = 1.6666667
x = 4.6666667

det = -3.0000

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What is the problem with my code that makes my output differ from the correct output given at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done the multiplication of the RHS vector by the inverse matrix incorrectly.

If the variables in your code x and y match your equation, then they shouldn't be arrays.  Your variable names are confusing.  I don't think of the RHS as solution; that's what x and y will be.  I'd call it b.

You replaced the matrix with its inverse.  You should just multiply the RHS vector by the inverse to get the solution.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main (void) {
    double a[2][2];
    double x[2];
    double b[2];

    printf("Give Numbers:\n");
    scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f" &a[0][0],  &a[0][1], &b[0], &a[1][0],  &a[1][1], &b[1]);


    double det;
    det = a[0][0]*a[1][1] - a[0][1]*a[1][0];

    double extra;
    extra = a[0][0];
    a[0][0] = a[1][1]/det;
    a[1][1] = extra/det;
    a[1][0] = -a[1][0]/det;
    a[0][1] = -a[0][1]/det;

    x[0] = a[0][0]*b[0]+a[0][1]*b[1];
    x[1] = a[1][0]*b[0]+a[1][1]*b[1];

    printf("x[0]' = %f\n" , x[0]);
    printf("zx[1] = %f\n" , x[1]);
    printf("Det= %f\n",det);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your code reads the input `{1 2 3 4 5}` it represents the equations

```
1 * x + 2 * y = 3
4 * x + 5 * y = 6
```

The correct answer is indeed `x = -1` , `y = 2`. Your program does not compute the correct answer because of the Multiplication part, which should read:

```
x[0] = coef[0][0] * solution[0] + coef[0][1] * solution[1];
x[1] = coef[1][0] * solution[0] + coef[1][1] * solution[1]
```

The reason being that once you have the inverse the only that remains is to multiply it by the `solution` vector.